# How to enable scrolling within LinearLayout within a scrollable RelativeLayout

Tags: android

I have tried several approaches to get this to work, but with no success so far. 
The main ScrollView is needed to enable scrolling between fragments. The RelativeLayout is there so we align the "Back/Save/Done" buttons at the bottom of the parent screen for all fragments.

Now in my code I added TableLayouts to the LinearLayout below programmatically (I also attempted this with GridViews instead of TableLayouts).

```
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/layout"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_above="@+id/PageRadioGroup"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:orientation="vertical" >
            </LinearLayout>
```

This LinearLayout is not scrollable, and the problem is that I have 4 tables and only the first table is visible. If I encase the LinearLayout within a ScrollView / NestedScrollView, then main parent ScrollView gets disabled.

How do I maintain the scrolling within the main ScrollView, keep the RelativeLayout structure and at the same time allow scrolling within the child LinearLayout to be able to view all the tables within it.

This is my layout xml

```
 <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dp" >

            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/PageRadioGroup"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="19dp"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <RadioButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:checked="true"
                    android:clickable="false" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:clickable="false" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:clickable="false" />
            </RadioGroup>

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="349dp"
                android:layout_above="@+id/PageRadioGroup"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true" >
            </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnBack"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:text="@string/back"
                android:textAllCaps="false" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnSave"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:text="@string/save"
                android:textAllCaps="false"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnDone"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/btnSave"
                android:text="@string/done"
                android:textAllCaps="false" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/layout"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_above="@+id/PageRadioGroup"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:orientation="vertical" >
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>

    </ScrollView>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Its not a good approach to put a vertical scroll container inside a vertical scroll container :) But you can try adding android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true" to your LinearLayout

Comment: android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true" did not work. Is there a way to make the LinearLayout scrollable without using an inner ScrollView?

Comment: The question is: Is the LinearLayout supposed to be scrollable? Or is there a layout problem?

Comment: LinearLayout is not scrollable. But due to the fact that I am having multiple views inside it that are not visible, I would like it to scroll. The issue is I already have a main ScrollView (which I have to keep) and adding another scroll container disables it. I am trying to find a workaround, any suggestions?

Comment: I suggest to fix the LinearLayout height issue, so that it displays all childs without scrolling. Could you add the code where you add the childs?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to achieve what I wanted. Below is the updated layout xml. I believe the main fix was to change the height of the ViewPager to wrap_content. Then I added a NestedScrollView to the LinearLayout. The Tables are programmatically added to LinearLayout with android:id="@+id/Layout".

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp" >

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/PageRadioGroup"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="19dp"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:checked="true"
                android:clickable="false" />

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:clickable="false" />

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:clickable="false" />
        </RadioGroup>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/Pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/PageRadioGroup"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true" >
        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnBack"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:text="@string/back"
            android:textAllCaps="false"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnSave"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:text="@string/save"
            android:textAllCaps="false"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnDone"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/btnSave"
            android:text="@string/done"
            android:textAllCaps="false" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/PageRadioGroup"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:isScrollContainer="true" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/Layout"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >
                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```